# Endpoint Not found when running specific method from same service

Tags: c#, wcf

All I am trying to run a WCF service but when I try to call a specific service method, I get an error

> Endpoint was not found

after hosting on 3rd party hosting server.

This is my `.SVC.cs` code

```
public class AUTOHUBWITHSQL : IAUTOHUBWITHSQL
{
        ClsDataAccess ObjData = new ClsDataAccess();

        public Responce Login(string sEmail, string sPassword)
        {
            Responce responce = new Responce();
            string sJson = "";

            try
            {
                sJson = ObjData.GetData("EXEC ProcLogin @email='" + sEmail + "',@Password='" + sPassword + "',@flag='L'");
                responce.Data = sJson;
                responce.Success = true;
                responce.Error = "";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                sJson = ex.Message.ToString();
            }

            return responce;
        }

        public Responce AlterCustomerDocument(string data)
        {
            Responce responce = new Responce();
            string sJson = "";

            try
            {
                CustomerDocument cusdoc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomerDocument>(data);
                string sProstring = "EXEC ProcCustomerDocument @id='" + cusdoc.id + "',@Userid='" + cusdoc.Userid + "',@VehiclelNo='" + cusdoc.VehiclelNo + "'";
                sProstring += ",@VehicleType='" + cusdoc.VehicleType + "',@DocumentType='" + cusdoc.DocumentType + "',DocumentName='" + cusdoc.DocumentName + "' ,@flag='L'";
                sJson = ObjData.AlterDB(sProstring);

                if (sJson.Equals("Sucess"))
                {
                    responce = GETCustomerDocument(Convert.ToInt32(cusdoc.Userid));
                }

                responce.Success = true;
                responce.Error = "";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                sJson = ex.Message.ToString();
            }

            return responce;
        }

        public Responce GETCustomerDocument(int iUserid)
        {
            Responce responce = new Responce();
            string sJson = "";

            try
            {
                string sProstring = "EXEC ProcCustomerDocument @Userid='" + iUserid + "',@flag='S'";
                sJson = ObjData.GetData(sProstring);
                responce.Data = sJson;
                responce.Success = true;
                responce.Error = "";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                sJson = " Faild";
                responce.Error = ex.Message.ToString() + sJson;
            }

            return responce;
        }
}
```

This my `IAUTOHUBWITHSQL` interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IAUTOHUBWITHSQL
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "Login?sEmail={sEmail}&sPassword={sPassword}")]
    Responce Login(string sEmail, string sPassword);
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "AlterCustomerDocument?data={data}")]
    Responce AlterCustomerDocument(string data);
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "GETCustomerDocument?Userid={iUserid}")]
    Responce GETCustomerDocument(int iUserid);
}
```

In `IAUTOHUBWITHSQL`, the `Login` method is working fine but while running post 2 method, I get this "Endpoint not found" error.

This is my `web.config` file:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" defaultLanguage="c++7">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="AutoHubWITHSQL.AUTOHUBWITHSQL" 
                 behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior">
            <endpoint 
                address="" 
                binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="jsonBehavior" 
                contract="AutoHubWITHSQL.IAUTOHUBWITHSQL" />
            <!--
            <endpoint 
                address=""
                binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="web"
                contract="AutoHub.IAutoHubService">
            </endpoint>
            -->
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <!--
            <behavior name="web">
                <webHttp/>
            </behavior>
            -->
            <behavior name="jsonBehavior">
                <webHttp />
            </behavior>
            <behavior name="webBehavior">
                <webHttp helpEnabled="true" 
                         automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false" />
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <extensions>
        <behaviorExtensions>
            <add name="crossOriginResourceSharingBehavior" 
                 type="AutoHub.EnableCrossOriginResourceSharingBehavior, AutoHub, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" />
        </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.10.0" newVersion="2.6.10.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.10.0" newVersion="2.6.10.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>

  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: There are no host or base address for any endpoint ,how come login is working?.

Comment: @hameed can you help me out  for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing,You dont have any base address so you need to add one.Assuming one address .

```
 <host>
         <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/" />
         </baseAddresses>
        </host>
```

Now your service is hosted at http://localhost:8080/

Since you have address as "" ,it means only one endpoint can be accessed by default ,do provide a relative name to the addresses.

```
      <endpoint 
                address="HubSQL" 
                binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="jsonBehavior" 
                contract="AutoHubWITHSQL.IAUTOHUBWITHSQL" />
            <!--
            <endpoint 
                address="Hubservice"
                binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="web"
                contract="AutoHub.IAutoHubService">
            </endpoint>
```

**IAUTOHUBWITHSQL** related contracts can be accessed at   http://localhost:8080/HubSQL/ and **IAutoHubService** contracts 
 http://localhost:8080/Hubservice/

```
    <behavior name="web">
        <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
```

Comment: thnks for replay but after adding endpoint address it showing 404 error address not found

Comment: Remove the comment for web behavior.